# changing all the logs to another branch

Tags: git

Sorry for the poor title but this is my problem:

I initialized my repo and worked my way always in the master branch.
Now, i would like to:

- create a branch `develop`,
- make it seem that all my commits were to that branch
- have `master` only have the log for the branch with `develop`

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: A branch is just a named reference to a specific commit. The log are all commits from the head (or currently checked out commit) to the first commit. With this in mind, I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain better?

Comment: Yes, the question is unclear. What do you mean by "have master only have the log for the branch with develop"? How can a branch have the log of another branch? That does not make sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried it but couldn't you rename your `master` branch with

```
git branch -m master develop
```

and make a new `master` branch?